# how to convert the file as to xml

Tags: xml, symfony, yaml, symfony-2.1

## how to convert the file to xml

### MyFile ~/doctrine/User.orm.yml

```
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
type: entity 
table: fos_user id: id:
    type: integer
    generator:
        strategy: AUTO

manyToMany:
    groups:
        targetEntity: Group
        joinTable:
            name: fos_user_group
            joinColumns:
                user_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                group_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

this file is in user.orm.yml format But i want it as file_name.orm.xml....
so i want to convert it as the xml one...
how can i do this?

Comment: I don't think that there's any tool available. But you only have to bring in into this [schema by doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the Entity in your database (if it does not already exist), and then doctrine:mapping:import which should create the corresponding XML for you

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeUserBundle xml
```

See [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) for more help.